# Why does Django not recognize my imported model?

Tags: python, django

I have an app called `feeder` which itself has the files `models.py` and `feeder.py`.

Now I would like to import the models `StocksInfo` and `StocksPrice` into `feeder.py` in order to update my database with the fetched data.

Somehow it doesn't import the models and throws an error. Where is the missing piece?

**Error:**

```
C:\Users\Jonas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe C:/Users/Jonas/Desktop/CFD/CFD/feeder/feeder.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Jonas/Desktop/CFD/CFD/feeder/feeder.py", line 50, in <module>
    getStocksInfo();
  File "C:/Users/Jonas/Desktop/CFD/CFD/feeder/feeder.py", line 34, in getStocksInfo
    obj, created = StocksInfo.objects.update_or_create(
AttributeError: type object 'StocksInfo' has no attribute 'objects'
```

**feeder.py**

```
import requests

# import the required models does not work, they are greyed out + underlined red in IDE
from feeder.models import StocksInfo, StocksPrice

# Define stocksInfo Query Function
def getStocksInfo():

    # query stocksInfo and populate it to the database
    stocksInfo = requests.get('https://finnhub.io/api/v1/stock/profile2?symbol=AAPL&token=bqtcoffrh5re54ulvqig')
    stocksInfo = stocksInfo.json()

    # assign variables
    #TODO assign symbol to variable for populate check
    symbol = 'APPL'
    country = stocksInfo['country']
    exchange = stocksInfo['exchange']
    name = stocksInfo['name']
    ticker = stocksInfo['ticker']
    ipoDate = stocksInfo['ipo']
    marketCapitalization = stocksInfo['marketCapitalization']
    shareOutstanding = stocksInfo['shareOutstanding']
    logo = stocksInfo['logo']
    url = stocksInfo['weburl']
    industry = stocksInfo['finnhubIndustry']

    # update database
    obj, created = StocksInfo.objects.update_or_create(
        symbol=symbol,
        defaults={
            'country': country,
            'exchange': exchange,
            'name': name,
            'ticker': ticker,
            'ipoDate': ipoDate,
            'marketCapitalization': marketCapitalization,
            'shareOutstanding': shareOutstanding,
            'logo': logo,
            'url': url,
            'industry': industry,
        }
    )

getStocksInfo();
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class StocksInfo(models.Model):
    symbol = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=False)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    exchange = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    ticker = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    ipoDate = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    marketCapitalization = models.FloatField(max_length=30, blank=False)
    shareOutstanding = models.FloatField(max_length=30, blank=False)
    logo = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=False)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=False)
    industry = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)

    StocksInfo = models.Manager()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'StocksInfo'


class StocksPrice(models.Model):
    priceO = models.FloatField(max_length=15, blank=False)
    priceH = models.FloatField(max_length=15, blank=False)
    priceL = models.FloatField(max_length=15, blank=False)
    priceC = models.FloatField(max_length=15, blank=False)
    pricePC = models.FloatField(max_length=15, blank=False)

    StocksPrice = models.Manager()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'StocksPrice'
```

There are no migrations to run and my app `feeder` is included in my project's `settings.py`.

Comment: You import `stockInfo`, and just after that define a function with the same name. What do you think is going to happen when you call `stockInfo()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overriding the `stocksInfo` variable with the results of `requests.get`, so when you try to call `stocksInfo.objects`, you are actually referencing the JSON dict from your request, and not your model.

I'd recommend using uppercase names for models to avoid errors like this.

Comment: lessons learned in terms of name conventions. I changed both the models in models.py and the according related inputs in feeder.py + made the migrations. However, it still throws a similar error. Updated everything in the initial post.

Comment: @Phanti I'm not able to reproduce your error after the update.  Can you share a github link to your repo?  I could probably find the error then.

Comment: Thanks for the offer, I don't have a GitHub repo tho. I removed the custom managers from the two models and then it worked... I don't know what kind of issure they caused though. thx again for your time

Comment: @Phanti Ah yeah, that was the issue.  Adding a custom manager prevents Django from adding the default `objects` manager.

Answer (score 0):

You have overwrited ta model name to the data recived from url as get method,
Thats means stocksInfo is no more a name of a model after you used that as veriable to name the data get from api url, Use seperete name for model and data get from 
requests.get('https://finnhub.io/api/v1/stock/profile2?symbol=AAPL&token=##########')
you can save data to stocksInfo model as follows

import requests

## import the required models does not work, they are greyed out + underlined red in IDE

from feeder.models import stocksInfo, stocksPrice

## Define stocksInfo Query Function

def stocksInfo():

```
# Query stocksInfo and populate it to the database
stocks = requests.get('https://finnhub.io/api/v1/stock/profile2?symbol=AAPL&token=###############')
stocks= stocksInfo.json()

# Assign data to variables    
symbol = 'APPL'
country = stocks['country']
exchange = stocks['exchange']
name = stocks['name']
ticker = stocks['ticker']
ipoDate = stocks['ipo']
marketCapitalization = stocks['marketCapitalization']
shareOutstanding = stocks['shareOutstanding']
logo = stocks['logo']
url = stocks['weburl']
industry = stocks['finnhubIndustry']

# create object and update database
obj, created = stocksInfo.objects.update_or_create(
    symbol=symbol,
    defaults={
        'country': country,
        'exchange': exchange,
        'name': name,
        'ticker': ticker,
        'ipoDate': ipoDate,
        'marketCapitalization': marketCapitalization,
        'shareOutstanding': shareOutstanding,
        'logo': logo,
        'url': url,
        'industry': industry,
    }
)
```

stocksInfo();

Answer (score 0):

I removed the Managers from the Models and migrated once again, now it works...But for gods sake I do not know what the custom managers caused that it returned the error. Any ideas?